# Enable / Disable JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have in my website, some javascript code that is responsible for the scrolling in the site.

I want to create trigger button so the users can enable/disable it.

```
<script src="/plugins/js/somejs1.js"></script>
<script src="/plugins/js/somejs2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // some js (the code i want make a trigger button)
</script>
<span type="checkbox" id="the1" checked>
 Display/Hide Button
</span>
<div id="trigger1">
 Text Text Text
</div>
```

Can it be done with PHP ?

Comment: PHP runs server-side. Javascript runs client-side. You'll want to run some javascript function upon clicking the "trigger button".

Comment: You don't need PHP for that. PHP simply outputs HTML/JS. A button to enable or disable that would be pure JS.

Comment: No, it cannot be done with php. Yes, you can do it with javascript, but it will depend on what the "some javascript code" does.

Comment: Also, technically it could be done with PHP.. you could send a GET flag to not include JS files, which would, in effect, disable the javascript on the site. A session variable could be used to remember this request for the user, and then could be turned back on using another GET parameter in the request..

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 But then each enabling/disabling action would require a reload of the page (or at least parts of the page), which is completely unnecessary.

Comment: im using jquery infinite scrolling. http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

Comment: @Darksane Infinite scrolling is terrible from a UX perspective ([relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1309/)). I would seriously think about whether or not it's really necessary before using this "feature" in the first place.

Comment: @NullUserException I just said it was possible.. not preferred...

Answer (score 0):

**part one:**

to do it purely with javascript:

try saving a cookie with a true/false value to keep the scrollingEnabled value, and then using a regular button change it from true to false and vice versa accordingly

to do it with php: print an element with an attribute or inner text 'true' / 'false' or set a cookie.

**part two**

in that scrolling function first check the cookie or your custom element and execute the function's code according to the value u have.